# "unsupported_grant_type" after publishing WebApi on Azure

Tags: azure, authentication, asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory, owin

I'm creating a WebApi that access a database hosted on Azure. After implementing Token Based Authentication it works perfectly locally, but after publishing it on Azure, when I try to get an access token I keep receiving the message: `"error": "unsupported_grant_type"` when testing it on Postman. Do I need to configure something else on Azure?

I'm requesting my token with the following parameters/settings:

```
"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
username: xxx
password: xxx
grant_type: password
```

As I said, using these parameters I'm receiving my access token just fine locally (as seen below), the problem only occurs after deploying it to Azure.

```
{
    "access_token": "Daak3ZrEzMkcd-dCbEdN0FTjdc9QYexA5wfHtYBRQIdx0dJtX1RL3LR6rqXhKvr84J6qS0CyDwuVw3w3T-b6iXtVG3utqTda98EcQJUgDZjvnq6tgsml4tbkAQRYLX0BPYidk5JvdRHMLaoQkP3vYJYnCefWPN-jBPb9xdyyk-ZtgOxKVUcBECGeZeWKkSl2ZL7Mtg_opc5ryxedQbNcQkFAk1z4oBEuYSaUllGHJlswqq1lbZq-BUOTwroZFzae",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599
}
```

locally:
[postman request made locally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cG4B.png)

after deploying to azure:
[postman request made after deploy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hB3rH.png)

So far I haven't made a request via code, only using postman

Has anyone faced a similar problem? Thanks!

Comment: Could you please add your token request sample.

Comment: are you trying with personal account like example@outlook.com ?

Comment: Was my answer resolve your problem? Do you have any more query? Let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback man, I'll read the link you sent me and try to change my implementation, and as soon as possible i'll come back here to say if it worked. Once again thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are trying to use `Resource owner password credential (ROPC)` to access your API. But this flow has little restriction on azure portal.

***Please read the `Important` note carefully.***

[image]

**You could Use:**

`MatheusSchneider@YourTennant.onmicrosoft.com`

*But Not* `MatheusSchneider@outlook.com`

> **Note:** As Microsoft does not recommend this authentication flow this may be the cause after deployment on `azure portal`. I would
>   suggest you to use some other authentication flow instead of this. You
>   could check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow)